# Program to Change all images urls in the html response to be downloaded from two domains

Tags: java, url-rewriting, pattern-matching, servlet-filters

I need some help in trying to figure out the java code to replace image URLs with two domains (mapping to the same site), to ensure that IE can download those files in parallel (achieve more than 2 files download trick for IE).
My Basic Design is have a ResponseWrapper filter which has the handle on response data.

Now once I have the html string, I want to replace every img url with 2 domains alternatively

I have the html with me which contains the following patttern as an example

<... href="/img/abc/def.jpg/>
<....src="/img/ghi/ijk.jpg/>
<....src="/img/ghi/xyz.jpg/>
<... href="/img/abc/lkm.jpg/>

I want to find this pattern and replace it with the following string

<... href="http://test1.com/img/abc/def.jpg/>
<....src="http://test2.com/img/ghi/ijk.jpg/>
<....src="http://test1.com/img/ghi/xyz.jpg/>
<... href="http://test2.com/img/abc/lkm.jpg/>
and so on.

Can somebody give me an idea of what should be the logic or algorithm to do this pattern replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to do this on the response text itself, you should create a method to generate URLs. This method would randomly pick a host from some configured list (there's no good reason to strictly alternate).

Comment: The main issue here is amount of change needed to do this during generation of URLs as most of it is in the code spread all across the application. Therefore using a filter is the only feasible solution I have come up with

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do, and I would suggest you to do the same:

- put your main domain with **`www`**
- put your images domain #1 into **`im1`**
- put your images domain #2 into **`im2`**

In your web pages, just put full links to images like:

- **`http://im1.example.com/image1.jpg`**
- **`http://im2.example.com/image2.jpg`**

But my first advice would be: read carefully all the recommandations from the YahooSlow plugin, which are the best ones about website optimization.